# Mount and Blade Warband - Game crashes when choosing the 'Load Game' option

Tags: technical-issues, mount-and-blade-warband, mount-and-blade

Very recently my version of Mount and Blade Warband on Steam has been crashing every single time I try to choose the 'Load Game' option in the main screen, or the 'Save As' option on the in game screen.

I am running my game on a desktop computer with Ubuntu 14.04 x64 installed. I have not had any problems playing the game and it had never crashed until today, and I am unable to load my previous characters and continue to play.

Here is my rgl_log.txt contents in case that helps solve the problem.

```
Starting new log file.
 Version:  1.168 
 Received stats and achievements from Steam

 Processing Ini File {
 Module_name =  Calradia 
 Num Hints =  12 
 Setting Map Min X =  -180.000000 
 Setting Map Max X =  180.000000 
 Setting Map Min Y =  -145.000000 
 Setting Map Max Y =  145.000000 
 Setting Time Multiplier =  0.250000 
 Setting Seeing Range Multiplier =  6.500000 
 Setting Track Spotting Multiplier =  0.800000 
 Setting player_wounded_treshold =  5.000000 
 Setting hero_wounded_treshold =  15.000000 
 Setting Skill Prisoner Management Bonus =  5 
 Setting Skill Leadership Bonus =  3 
 Setting Base Companion Limit =  20 
 Setting player_xp_multiplier =  2.000000 
 Setting hero_xp_multiplier =  2.000000 
 Setting regulars_xp_multiplier =  3.000000 
 Setting damage_interrupt_attack_treshold =  3.000000 
 Setting damage_interrupt_attack_treshold_mp =  1.000000 
 Setting armor_soak_factor_against_cut =  0.800000 
 Setting armor_soak_factor_against_pierce =  0.650000 
 Setting armor_soak_factor_against_blunt =  0.500000 
 Setting armor_reduction_factor_against_cut =  1.000000 
 Setting armor_reduction_factor_against_pierce =  0.500000 
 Setting armor_reduction_factor_against_blunt =  0.750000 
 Setting horse_charge_damage_multiplier =  1.000000 
 Setting couched_lance_damage_multiplier =  0.650000 
 Setting fall_damage_multiplier =  1.000000 
 Setting shield_penetration_offset =  30.000000 
 Setting shield_penetration_factor =  3.000000 
 Setting missile_damage_speed_power =  1.900000 
 Setting melee_damage_speed_power =  2.000000 
 Setting multiplayer_walk_enabled =  0 
 Setting mission_object_prune_time =  180 
 Scan Module Textures =  1 
 Scan Module Sounds =  0 
 Loading Resource  test 
 Loading Resource  textures_face_gen 
 Loading Resource  shaders 
 Loading Resource  textures 
 Loading Resource  materials 
 Loading Resource  materials_face_gen 
 Loading Resource  uimeshes 
 Loading Resource  meshes_face_gen 
 Loading Resource  helpers 
 Loading Resource  map_tree_meshes 
 Loading Resource  map_icon_meshes 
 Loading Resource  particle_meshes 
 Loading Resource  skeletons 
 Loading Resource  tree_meshes 
 Loading Resource  xtree_meshes 
 Loading Resource  grass_meshes 
 Loading Resource  plant_meshes 
 Loading Resource  body_meshes 
 Loading Resource  object_meshes 
 Loading Resource  object_bodies 
 Loading Resource  goods_meshes 
 Loading Resource  item_meshes1 
 Loading Resource  horse_a 
 Loading Resource  arabian_horses 
 Loading Resource  arabian_castle 
 Loading Resource  food 
 Loading Resource  beards 
 Loading Resource  armors_b 
 Loading Resource  armors_c 
 Loading Resource  armors_d 
 Loading Resource  armors_e 
 Loading Resource  armors_f 
 Loading Resource  armors_g 
 Loading Resource  armors_h 
 Loading Resource  armors_i 
 Loading Resource  boots_b 
 Loading Resource  boots_c 
 Loading Resource  helmets 
 Loading Resource  helmets_b 
 Loading Resource  village_houses 
 Loading Resource  village_houses_a 
 Loading Resource  village_houses_b 
 Loading Resource  hair 
 Loading Resource  deneme 
 Loading Resource  interiors_a 
 Loading Resource  interiors_b 
 Loading Resource  interiors_c 
 Loading Resource  arena 
 Loading Resource  map_icons_b 
 Loading Resource  castle_a 
 Loading Resource  dungeon 
 Loading Resource  stone_houses 
 Loading Resource  snowy_houses 
 Loading Resource  snowy_castle 
 Loading Resource  helmets_d 
 Loading Resource  helmets_e 
 Loading Resource  helmets_f 
 Loading Resource  castle_b 
 Loading Resource  square_keep 
 Loading Resource  anim_b 
 Loading Resource  shields 
 Loading Resource  shields_b 
 Loading Resource  weapon_meshes_c 
 Loading Resource  xtree_meshes_b 
 Loading Resource  map_icons_c 
 Loading Resource  pictures 
 Loading Resource  user_interface_b 

rgl_post_warning_line: WARNING: Unable to find material mp_ui_host_maps_e for mesh mp_ui_host_maps_e1 
rgl_post_warning_line: WARNING: Unable to find material mp_ui_host_maps_e for mesh mp_ui_host_maps_e2 Loading Resource  user_interface_c 
 Loading Resource  scene_encounter_spot 
 Loading Resource  interior_thirsty_lion 
 Loading Resource  scene_small_tavern 
 Loading Resource  weapon_meshes1 
 Loading Resource  weapon_meshes_b 
 Loading Resource  houses1 
 Loading Resource  wall_meshes1 
 Loading Resource  town_houses 
 Loading Resource  doors 
 Loading Resource  churches 
 Loading Resource  town_houses_b 
 Loading Resource  castle_c 
 Loading Resource  castle_d 
 Loading Resource  castle_e 
 Loading Resource  castle_f 
 Loading Resource  castle_g 
 Loading Resource  castle_h 
 Loading Resource  castle_i 
 Loading Resource  gatehouse 
 Loading Resource  viking_houses 
 Loading Resource  fake_houses 
 Loading Resource  town_houses_c 
 Loading Resource  banners 
 Loading Resource  map_flags 
 Loading Resource  map_flags_b 
 Loading Resource  map_flags_c 
 Loading Resource  map_flags_d 
 Loading Resource  particles_2 
 Loading Resource  prisons 
 Loading Resource  prisons_b 
 Loading Resource  interiors_d 
 Loading Resource  costumes_b 
 Loading Resource  costumes_c 
 Loading Resource  arena_costumes 
 Loading Resource  boots_a 
 Loading Resource  terrain_borders 
 Loading Resource  terrain_borders_b 
 Loading Resource  skyboxes 
 Loading Resource  object_b 
 Loading Resource  tree_e_meshes 
 Loading Resource  destroy 
 Loading Resource  xtree_meshes_c 
 Loading Resource  grass_meshes_b 
 Loading Resource  interiors_steppe 
 Loading Resource  grooming_horse 
 Loading Resource  town_houses_d 
 Loading Resource  horses_b 
 Loading Resource  ani_horse_mounted 
 Loading Resource  deneme2 
 Loading Resource  horse_skeleton 
 Loading Resource  steppe_fake_houses 
 Loading Resource  weapon_meshes_d 
 Loading Resource  tableau_shields 
 Loading Resource  heraldic_armors 
 Loading Resource  spear 
 Loading Resource  weapons_e 
 Loading Resource  weapons_f 
 Loading Resource  instruments 
 Loading Resource  sarranid_armors 
 Loading Resource  custom_banner 
 Loading Resource  simple_primitives 
 Loading Resource  ani_man_walk 
 Loading Resource  ani_twohanded 
 Loading Resource  ani_onehanded 
 Loading Resource  ani_death 
 Loading Resource  ani_stand_guardsman 
 Loading Resource  ani_human_mounted 
 Loading Resource  ani_lady_stand 
 Loading Resource  ani_poses 
 Loading Resource  ani_stand_shopkeeper 
 Loading Resource  ani_man_cheer 
 Loading Resource  ani_stand_onhorse 
 Loading Resource  ani_throw_stone 
 Loading Resource  ani_strikes 
 Loading Resource  ani_equip_arms 
 Loading Resource  ani_run_p 
 Loading Resource  ani_run_forward_left_right 
 Loading Resource  uni_strikes3 
 Loading Resource  ani_walk_sideways 
 Loading Resource  ani_run_sideways 
 Loading Resource  ani_stand 
 Loading Resource  ani_crouch_down 
 Loading Resource  ani_low_walk 
 Loading Resource  ani_turn_man 
 Loading Resource  ani_attacks_single 
 Loading Resource  ani_lancer 
 Loading Resource  ani_attacks 
 Loading Resource  ani_kicks 
 Loading Resource  ani_parry_attack 
 Loading Resource  ani_walk_backward 
 Loading Resource  ani_run_lookingsides 
 Loading Resource  ani_defends 
 Loading Resource  ani_walk_lookingsides 
 Loading Resource  ani_jump 
 Loading Resource  ani_wedding 
 Loading Resource  arabian_props 
 Loading Resource  uni_jump 
 Loading Resource  uni_stances 
 Loading Resource  uni_equip 
 Loading Resource  uni_strike 
 Loading Resource  uni_throws 
 Loading Resource  uni_fistswing 
 Loading Resource  uni_lord_stand 
 Loading Resource  uni_defence 
 Loading Resource  uni_sideways 
 Loading Resource  dart 
 Loading Resource  armors_new_a 
 Loading Resource  armors_new_b 
 Loading Resource  armors_new_heraldic 
 Loading Resource  armors_new_arena 
 Loading Resource  crossbows 
 Loading Resource  arabian_armors 
 Loading Resource  rock 
 Loading Resource  costumes_d 
 Loading Resource  nordic_helmets 
 Loading Resource  sarranid_helmets 
 Loading Resource  sarranid_armor 
 Loading Resource  raw_materials 
 Loading Resource  khergit_lady_dress 
 Loading Resource  vaegir_helmets 
 Loading Resource  gauntlets_new 
 Loading Resource  sarranid_lady_dress 
 Loading Resource  sarranid_boots 
 Loading Resource  bride_dress 
 Loading Resource  full_plate_armor 
 Loading Resource  weapon_meshes_e 
 Loading Resource  fur_armors_a 
 Loading Resource  ui_server_filter 
 Loading Resource  warhorse_new 
 Loading Resource  ship 
 Loading Resource  arabian_houses 
 Loading Resource  object_c 
 Loading Resource  tree_f 
 Loading Resource  interiors_arabian 
 Loading Resource  arabian_village 
 Loading Resource  valleyProps 
 Loading Resource  workshops 
 Loading Resource  barrier_primitives 
 Loading Resource  town_houses_e 
 Loading Resource  wb_mp_objects_a 

} //Processing Ini File Finished
 Loading Music...
 Loading Textures...
 Finished Loading Textures...
 L8 Format is  supported
 Sound file could not be found: Sounds/s_swordSwing.wav Sound file could not be found: Sounds/fl_pistol.wav WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP SOUND CODE:  snd_release_crossbow_medium 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP SOUND CODE:  snd_release_crossbow_far 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP SOUND CODE:  snd_bullet_hit_body 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP SOUND CODE:  snd_player_hit_by_bullet 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME PRESENTATION CODE:  prsnt_game_start 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME PRESENTATION CODE:  prsnt_game_escape 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME SCRIPT CODE:  game_check_party_sees_party 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME SCRIPT CODE:  game_get_party_speed_multiplier 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME SCRIPT CODE:  game_missile_launch 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME SCRIPT CODE:  game_missile_dives_into_water 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME SCRIPT CODE:  game_troop_upgrades_button_clicked 
 WARNING: UNABLE TO MAP GAME SCRIPT CODE:  game_character_screen_requested 
 Loading Module...
 Loading item kinds...
 Loading dialogs...
 Loading mission templates...
 Loading party templates...

rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: equip_musket 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: equip_musket 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_stand_man 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_stand_man 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_greatsword_cstance 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_staff_cstance 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_fire_pistol 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_fire_pistol 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: man_reload 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: man_reload 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: man_reload 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_staff_cstance_attack 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: crouch_staff_cstance_attack 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: spear_thrust_overhead 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: spear_thrust_overhead 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: spear_thrust_overhead 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: spear_thrust_overhead 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: spear_thrust_overhead 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: reload_pistol_new 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_upper_swing 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_upper_swing 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_upper_swing 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_upper_swing 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_upper_swing 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_thrust_forward 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_thrust_forward 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_thrust_forward 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_thrust_forward_parry 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: musket_thrust_forward_parry 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: equip_pistol 
rgl_post_warning_line: get_skeleton_anim failed for: equip_pistol loading time:  24088 
 Finished All...
```

Please let me know if there is anything else that I can provide in order to help you help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried verifying your game installation in Steam?

Comment: Are you using any mod? Or was the same from a different mod?

Comment: In my case it was corrupted save file. Deleting it and restoring `last_savegame_backup.sav` fixed the problem.

Comment: i recommend you to backup all your savegames, and then delete them all, and try again the "save as" option, then, if that is working just fine, is PROBABLY that one of your saves is corrupted, copy each save in the saves folder one each time, and then test if that is the one corrupted, or you could just try to copy only the one you want.